# System Monitor appearing off screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, system-monitor

Running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I'm having System Monitor appear offscreen (see screenshot below). I've attempted a few things I found in some other posts here: installed CompizConfig Settings Wizard, enabled Place Windows which didn't work. I also followed another user's response that worked for them stating to also enable Snapping Windows, however this didn't work either.

[image]

Also, I attempted to alt + tab into System Monitor and then Alt + Space to open it's menu and Press "M" but it didn't allow me to move the application.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Whenever I launch System Monitor, it launches in the top corner and the window is stuck. I haven't had success with fixing where it launches, however I have found a fix to make it usable.

If you select the System Monitor window then press your "super + up arrow (or left or right arrow)" it will force full screen or move the window to snap side screen. Your "super" key is the Windows or Start key.

Answer (score -1):

If you hold the Alt key down you can drag any window even when clicking in the middle of it. This still doesn't stop it appearing offscreen every time.

Comment: Tested it. Doesn't work. But holding down the Win/Super-key does work. Maybe you like to change your answer accordingly.